# every flutter compiling console output repeat previous console output

Tags: android, flutter

after last update of flutter every time that I run a flutter program in the emulator I get a repeatition of previous output, added from the previous etc. So after 20 or 40 running and the output of the repetions is too long.
Seems that Gradle capture previous output.

What I've tried:
- reinstalled android studio
- reinstalled sdk
- flutter clean
- clear .gradle inside project

flutter version: v1.12.13+hotfix.5
android studio: 3.5.3

```
 D:\PROGRAMMING>flutter run
 Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling
 software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
 Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

repetition starts here...

```
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6176): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6176): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6176): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
I/flutter ( 6378): Test============================
I/flutter ( 6378): https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCnEA__kWb7t-Sx4miFDGFgw
I/flutter ( 6378): FeedChannelType.atom
```

ends here

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
     Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        19,7s
     √ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
     Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                         1,6s
     Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
      8.235ms (!)

```
   To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
 An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:52731/97amqE-0rd8=/
 For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
```

I dunno how to fix this problem, and why can be happen something like that.